# phonegap 1.5 & jquery mobile, backbutton event not fire (Android)?

Tags: jquery, mobile, cordova, back-button

my index.html code is

```
<div data-role="page" id="indexPage">
  <ul data-role="listview"> 
    <li>
        <a href="#childrenPage" >
            <h3>TITLE</h3>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="childrenPage">
    ****content word****
</div>
```

my js code is

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){            
       document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){ alert("back") }, false);
             alert("TEST")
    })
});
```

if the page is "indexPage", touch backbutton
alert("back") and alert("TEST") ---> fire

if changepage to "childrenPage", touch backbutton 
alert("back")---> not fire
alert("TEST")---> fire

How can I do that? 
i hope backbutton event fire with "childrenPage"

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function onLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to call Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
  alert("back");
  var currentPageId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    if(currentPageId == 'indexPage') {
      alert("TEST");
    } else if(currentPageId == 'childrenPage') {
      $.mobile.changePage("#indexPage", {transition : "slide"});
    }
 }
</script>
<body onload="onLoad()">
<div data-role="page" id="indexPage">
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="childrenPage">
</div>
</body>
```